# Whitespace in XML elements containing only text

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, whitespace

Say I have some XML that contains a tag that looks like this:

```
<tag_name>  Content  </tag_name>
```

Or this:

```
<tag_name>
  Content
</tag_name>
```

Should the whitespace on either end of the text content of the tag be considered part of the content?  I don't see this explicitly addressed in the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/), but the Text Encoding Initiative [seems to say](http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/XML_Whitespace#Text-Only_Elements) it should be collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML itself considers the whitespace to be part of the content.

Whether your particular XML-based language does is up to you. If not, then it will be the responsibility of applications which process that language to strip off the whitespace.